# How many trophies are there in total in Fable 3?

Tags: achievements, fable-3

Also, is there a complete list of them? The trophy room seems to have space for 12 trophies, but I can only seem to locate 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 9 of them; 12 slots are reserved for DLCs(as you can see by trophy at the bottom). Here's [source](http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/Trophies) with links to details about trophies.

- Guild Seal
- Saker's Flag
- Simmons's Head
- Balverine Head
- ???
- Gnome Trophy
- The Complete Works of Philipth Morley
- Orb of Magicka
- Normanomicon
- Chicken Trophy
- Teddy Bear *(Traitor's Keep DLC)*
- ???